# Regular expression to match a string between parenthesis and comma, but with multiple parenthesis present

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to use regex to match strings (which are species names+codes, e.g. diadema1479) in a phylogenetic tree in parenthetical notation, but I'm not being successful to deal with all the parenthesis.

Here's a sample of my data

```
(diadema1479:0.20268621848058304691,longipes1483:0.18941326141716441356):0.05754190478991345892,((sp1_11269:0.08954446656323425402,(davidovi11375:0.12866818058352805232):0.02407442773179632040):0.11326732171695803875,(((S_willeyi:0.16019503647856672690,(((((S_sp2:0.13155607959902493320,S_sp3:0.04602288122852762897):0.09795419683476988548,S_sp4:0.03464730266968370220):0.06696262102745857703,S_sp5_Lombok:0.00000100000050002909):0.01699644302538915949,((S_javensis:0.12205647213742974733,(S_sp6:0.07046365005123975123,((yayukae12168:0.01496242382530112158,(yayukae12109:0.01287526689678352571...
```

When I use:

```
/(?<=\()[^:]+/g
```

It matches, for example, 'diadema1479' and 'davidovi11375', but includes all extra parenthesis in '((((S_sp2'. How can I set it not to match any parenthesis at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you list out all of the expected matches from your sample data?

Comment: `[^:()]` matches neither colon nor parentheses.

Comment: In the most generic case, just make sure there is no `(` after `(`: `/(?<=\()(?!\()[^:]+/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
(?<=[(,])[^(:]+
```

- `(?<=[(,])` - make sure the previous char is an open parenthesis or a comma
- `[^(:]+` - match everything which is not an open parenthesis nor colon

https://regex101.com/r/8Yocnm/1

Answer (score 1):

Just add `(` in the character class:

```
(?<=\()[^(:]+
//     __^
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/zl6Psn/1)

Comment: This fails to find `S_sp5_Lombok`, `longipes1483`, and others

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: True, but do they need to match? Waiting for OP's clarification.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing that's why I haven't casted a vote yet :-)

Comment: @Toto this works perfectly! Thanks
@MonkeyZeus ```S_sp5_Lombok``` and ```longipes1483``` do not match because they have a comma before the name, not a parenthesis. I do need to make them match too; I was trying to figure this out by myself before posting here,  but I've not  been successful so far, if any of you could give recommendations, that would be very welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I just saw your answer below. That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: +one to you for gambling without clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative: `(\w+):`. In your example it looks like you're trying to get the usernames or whatever that is, after a ( and before a :. `\w+` finds "word" characters and the `:` allows excluding the float that follows.

Also, I can never recommend enough this website for regexp testing:
https://regex101.com/